# Making WinWindow Full Screen

Tags: c#

I am working on a C# test that when run opens an application as an instance of the WinWindow class. However, when it opens, it does not open full screen, which is affecting the test outcome. Is there a way to make the WinWindow be full screen?

I have tried `WinWindow.Maximized.Equals(true);` however this has given me no luck.

Answer (score 2):

`.Equals()` is a test for equality. Additionally, I don't believe that `Maximized` is a property on either the WPF Window class or the Winforms Form class.

What you actually want to do is set the `WindowState` proprty:

**WinForms**

`form.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;`

---

**WPF**

`window.WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;`

Comment: Actually what worked for me was `WinWindow.Maximized = true;`

Comment: ah I see, WinWindow is not a WPF or WinForms class. its some coded ui test class.

Comment: Indeed. Thank you for your help though!